# $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(t\sqrt{x^2-k^2})}{\sqrt{x^2-k^2}}=?$

Tags: limits

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(t\sqrt{x^2-k^2})}{\sqrt{x^2-k^2}}=?$

Anyone can help, please. 
Does is equal to $t$?

Comment: Isn't it $\lim_{x\to k?}$

Comment: ya, if $x \to k$, the result is $t$

Comment: the question is $\lim_{x\to 0}$

Answer (score 2):

if $\lim x\to k$ then you can make the substitution $\sqrt{x^2-k^2 } =y$

you get : $\lim_{y\to 0} \dfrac{\sin(t{y})}{{y}}=t$ (this is a well known limit)

Comment: More correctly $\lim_{y\to 0^+}$, although in this case it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(t\sqrt{x^2-k^2})}{\sqrt{x^2-k^2}}=\frac{\sin(t\sqrt{-k^2})}{\sqrt{-k^2}}$$

Comment: so it is not equal to t

Comment: but when $x\rightarrow k$ so it is equal to t

Comment: that is what I got so far, not sure if it is correct,